# How to show the image inside a div before uploading?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a five separated `<input>` files, i want any uploaded image to show inside its own div, so for example the first input file when i hit upload the image should show inside it div and so on .

The **problem** is that, i got the image inserted inside the first input file, even if i clicked one of the other inputs, for example, i want to upload a second image so the image simply should show inside the second div, but i got it always inside the first one .

**HTML CODE**:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="f-image first" id="1" data-up="1">
                <span class="handle"></span>
                <div class="image-upload">
                    <label>Add An Image</label>
                    <input name="userfile[]" type="file" class="up-button" type="file" onchange="readURL(this);">
                </div>
                <div id="result">
                    <img id="img-inside-small" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="f-image small" id="2" data-up="2">
                <span class="handle"></span>
                <div class="image-upload">
                    <label class="small">Add An Image</label>
                    <input name="userfile[]" type="file" class="up-button" type="file" onchange="readURL(this);">
                </div>
                <div id="result">
                    <img id="img-inside-small" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="f-image small" id="3" data-up="3">
                <span class="handle"></span>
                <div class="image-upload">
                    <label class="small">Add An Image</label>
                    <input name="userfile[]" type="file" class="up-button" type="file" onchange="readURL(this);">
                </div>
                <div id="result">
                    <img id="img-inside-small" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="f-image small" id="4" data-up="4">
                <span class="handle"></span>
                <div class="image-upload">
                    <label class="small">Add An Image</label>
                    <input name="userfile[]" type="file" class="up-button" type="file" onchange="readURL(this);">
                </div>
                <div id="result">
                    <img id="img-inside-small" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="f-image small" id="5" data-up="5">
                <span class="handle"></span>
                <div class="image-upload">
                    <label class="small">Add An Image</label>
                    <input name="userfile[]" type="file" class="up-button" type="file" onchange="readURL(this);">
                </div>
                <div id="result">
                    <img id="img-inside-small" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS CODE**:

```
function readURL(){
    $("input[type='file']").change(function(e) {

        for (var i = 0; i < e.originalEvent.srcElement.files.length; i++) {

            var file = e.originalEvent.srcElement.files[i];

            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function() {
                 // $('#img-inside-small').attr('src', reader.result);
                 $('#result').html('<img src="' +reader.result+ '" id="img-inside-small"/>');
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);        }
    });
}
```

Please, any suggestions guys ??

**UPDATE**:

the `<img id="img-inside-small" />` inside result `div` you can ignore it , i just forgot to remove it, `jquery` should do the job .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using an Id to set the html:
    $('#result').html('')

Do you know what the difference between an id and a class?

An id is a unique identifier. So you should only have one element on a page with a given id. You have given each of your divs the same ID. When you try to insert html into the selected div it just inserts into the first one.

You need a way to specify which div you would like to insert html into and give a unique identifier for each div..

One way could be that you pass the id of the element you would like to insert html into as a parameter in your method.

you pass "this"  from your inputs onchange event into the readUrl method but you never use it. You need to learn about using parameters in methods. You have also set the file type of your inputs twice...

Anways you can do something like this...

```
 <input type="file" onchange="readURL('div1');">
 <div id="div1"></div>
 <input type="file" onchange="readURL('div2');">
 <div id="div2"></div>


 <script>
 function readURL(divID){
$("input[type='file']").change(function(e) {

    for (var i = 0; i < e.originalEvent.srcElement.files.length; i++) {

        var file = e.originalEvent.srcElement.files[i];

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function() {
             // $('#img-inside-small').attr('src', reader.result);
             $('#' + divID).html('<img src="' +reader.result+ '" id="img-inside-small"/>');
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);        }
});
 }
 </script>
```

Alternatively you can use "this" on the inputs which you pass through but arent using, traverse the dom and find the div you want to update.

Comment: It worked mate, i really didn't noticed my mistakes but i got to learn more stuff about using parameters, its always my problem !! , again thanks alot for your interest :) .